# Typescript type is not being inferred from Prisma query

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have following schema in Prisma

```
model User {
  id              String      @id @default(uuid())
  name            String
  email           String      @unique
}
```

When I write the following typescript code, I expect the return type to be correctly inferred, but the `user` variable is beeing infered as `any` type. Is it how prisma works, or am I doing something wrong?

```js
const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    email: "abc@example.com",
  }
});
```

Btw, I am using Prisma version `5.2.0`

I have used the `npx prisma generate`. It generates proper type inference for input parameters. For example, if wrong field is set in where clause editor shows error. But only return value is inferred as `Promise<any>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the prisma client after defining your schema.primsa with `npx prisma generate` or `prisma generate` see Prisma docs in: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client

(This command reads your Prisma schema and generates the client in node_modules/@prisma/client, along with TypeScript typings for your models.)

Comment: I have used the `npx prisma generate`. It generates proper type inference for input parameters. For example, if wrong field is set in where clause editor shows error. But only return value is inferred as `Promise<any>`